# Horizontally center <p> within a div while keeping the text left-aligned

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

I have multiple divs with a fixed width containing `<p>` tags which contain various lengths of text.

I want this text to remain left-aligned but if the text does not take up as much space as the div width, I would like to align this text centrally.

I assume the best way of achieving this would be to horizontally center the `<p>` within the div while keeping the text left-aligned but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have tried setting `margin:0 auto;`but the `<p>` always resizes to the width of the div (unless I tell it otherwise, but I don't want to do this because if the text runs for longer than the div I don't want to break it early...)

I've set up a JSfiddle here to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/VDhUa/

(Basically in this example I would like to "Lorem ipsum..." stuff to be centrally aligned without using `text-align:center;`)

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want it to be centered if the string of text hass less width than the parent div? And left-aligned when it IS wider than the div?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set your outer div to `text-align: center;` and your inner p's to `display: inline-block;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZL4GM/

Comment: You beat me to it. It only works because the other two elements in the outer div are also centered.